# Movable big picture in the background

Tags: android, image

I have some layout and I want add to it big picture(3500x2200) in background.
I want move it when I click somewhere(it is some kind of map) - clicked point should be in screen center.

Example in C++ SFML it is easy - I created image bigger than screen and changed its position.

When I loading image to ImageView it is automatically scale to screen Width/Height.
I try scale this reduced images

```
android:scaleX="6"
android:scaleY="6"
```

and use this:

```
map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        map.setX(event.getX());
        map.setY(event.getY());
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it works strange.

Comment: are you trying to create some parallax effect?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. How to apply it?

Comment: like this http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2014/05/09/parallaxviewpager-parallax-background-effect-for-the-viewpager/?

Comment: I'm not sure it is what I want. I need not moving images/button in foreground and moving background image when I click.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution but it is not pretty.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    final int centerY = metrics.heightPixels/2;
    final int centerX = metrics.widthPixels/2;
```

and

```
map.setX(SCALE_X*(centerX-event.getX()));
map.setY(SCALE_Y*(centerY-event.getY()));
```

In my sample SCALE_X=SCALE_Y=6.

I don't know how it scalling will work with other screens.